# Obtain a URI using a session or server variable in PHP

Tags: php, uri

I want to obtain this part of my URI and assign it to a variable.

```
<?php 
$_SESSION[''] = 'http://www.devin-gray.webportfolio.capetown/cvnewsletter/';
?>
```

is it possible to use a `$_SESSION` or a `$_SERVER` function to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP documentation for $_SESSION or $_SERVER to find out? Do you know where to / how to find the documentation?

Comment: Is that the portion of the URI you want, or is that the entire URI?
You need to change $_SESSION[''] to something like $_SESSION['part_of_my_uri_to_store']

Comment: What documentation other than php.net do you know of? I am keen to check it out. Also I only want that part of the URI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start a $_SESSION you must do

```
session_start();
//What you want
session_write_close();
```

You can get the URI using

```
$_SESSION['uri'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Soz, auto posted when writting. Now fully writted

Answer (score 0):

use the following code , you left the index of the `$_SESSION` empty:

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = 'http://www.devin-gray.webportfolio.capetown/cvnewsletter/';
?>
```

start the session in another page where you wish to use this session variable.